# Como hago que la imagen sobresalga del menú

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Quiero que el logo que tengo en el menú sobresalga hacia arriba y no hacía abajo, la tengo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La quiero así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código html:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="block">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                      <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
                              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              </button>
                                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
                                  </a>
                            </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" id="top-nav">
                            <li><a href="#hero-area">Inicio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#slider">Servicios</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#blog">Galeria</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Menu<span class="caret"></span>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#hero-area">Tradicional</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#about-us">Eventos</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#subscribe">Reservas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#footer">Contacto</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .col-md-12 close -->
        </div><!-- .row close -->
    </div><!-- .container close -->
</nav><!-- header close -->
```

y el css:

```
nav {
z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;

}
nav .block {
  margin-top: -85px;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  background: rgba(102, 46, 28, 0.6);
  overflow: visible;
}

nav .block .navbar-default {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: none;
}
nav .block .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
nav .block .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Me parece que algo falta en este código, aca una captura https://imageshack.com/a/img924/4528/3TwJkH.png

Comment: Hablas de la imagen del vehiculo solamente? o esa es toda una sola imagen?, esa imagen es un background o es una imagen <img> ?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav hablo del logo que dice buenavista la flecha es para indicar que quiero subir ese logo. el carro hace parte de la imagen de fondo.

Comment: position:relative;top-30px;

Comment: ok, ese logo que dice buenavista es una imagen osea es un tag <img> o un background por css? es que no lo veo en el codigo que colocastes

Comment: ya se encuentra lo quite sin querer @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav

Comment: Trata de agregarle un z-index a la imagen o al padre de el osea a la etiquea <a> ponle un z-inde de 9999 para probar, me cuentas si te sirvio

Comment: No paso nada @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav

Comment: Una pregunta, estas queriendo que sobresalga no colocarlo mas arriba cierto? estas hablando del eje z y no del eje y cierto?

Comment: si, mas arriba o que sobresalga :v @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav

Comment: ok perfecto estare pendiente para ver lo que quieres en realidad asi ayudarte mejor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82848/discussion-between-leonard-jusa-ockonell-and-david-leonardo-molina-ruiz-dav).

Comment: Ahh ok perfecto quieres que este mas arriba con respecto a su margen no a su profundidad, perdona habia entendido mal, bueno colcale a la imagen margin-top:-100px, eso deberia de forzar a la imagen a subir, y ahi vas viendo como va quedando, avisame si funciona, quitale el z-index que te habia dicho

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, ya lo logre con la respuesta de abajo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No alcanzo a ver la imagen en tu código, pero puedes agregar el siguiente código a la imagen:

```
img{
position:relative; 
top:-15px;//aqui le daras un menos tanto dependiendo lo que nececites
}
```

intenta asi :

```
nav .block .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  position:relative; 
top:-15px;//aqui le daras un menos tanto dependiendo lo que nececites
}
```

Comment: Nada, no me funciono.

Comment: mira mi edicion

Comment: GRACIAS!! Funciono.

Comment: un placer ayudar saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

En tu css

```
nav { position:relative;}
nav .navbar-brand {position: absolute; z-index:300;}
```

Recuerda que el position absolute y los top,right,left y right se quedan dentro del div que tiene como position relative
Espero te sirva.

Comment: Se coloco el menu detras de la imagen.